# How to generate primefaces PickList component programmatically?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
public void populateForm(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) event.getComponent();

    List<String> citiesSource = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> citiesTarget = new ArrayList<String>();
    citiesSource.add("San Francisco");
    citiesSource.add("London");
    citiesSource.add("Paris");
    citiesSource.add("Istanbul");
    citiesSource.add("Berlin");
    citiesSource.add("Barcelona");
    citiesSource.add("Rome");

    cities = new DualListModel<String>(citiesSource, citiesTarget);

    PickList pickList = new PickList();
    pickList.setId("pickList");
    pickList.setValue(cities);
    pickList.setVar("cities");
    pickList.setItemLabel(pickList.getVar());
    pickList.setItemValue(cities);

     form.getChildren().add(pickList);
}
```

This was my approach, and output I got is:

[image]

But if I add `<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{bean.cities}" var="cities" itemLabel="#{cities}" itemValue="#{cities}" />` in my xhtml, I get this output:

[image]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the PickList issue:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExpressionFactory ef = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();

PickList pickList = new PickList();

ValueExpression pickListValue = ef.createValueExpression(
    context.getELContext(), "#{ruleManagedBean.cities}",DualListModel.class);

ValueExpression pickListVar = ef.createValueExpression(
            context.getELContext(), "cities", String.class);

ValueExpression pickListItemLabel = ef.createValueExpression(
            context.getELContext(), "#{cities}", String.class);

ValueExpression pickListItemValue = ef.createValueExpression(
            context.getELContext(), "#{cities}", String.class);

pickList.setId("pickList");
pickList.setValueExpression("value", pickListValue);
pickList.setValueExpression("var", pickListVar);
pickList.setValueExpression("itemLabel", pickListItemLabel);
pickList.setValueExpression("itemValue", pickListItemValue);

form.getChildren().add(pickList);
```

**Note:** ruleManagedBean.cities refers to the DualListModel, populated as

```
List<String> citiesSource = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> citiesTarget = new ArrayList<String>();
citiesSource.add("San Francisco");
citiesSource.add("London");
citiesSource.add("Paris");
citiesSource.add("Istanbul");
citiesSource.add("Berlin");
citiesSource.add("Barcelona");
citiesSource.add("Rome");

cities.setSource(citiesSource);
cities.setTarget(citiesTarget);
```

Make sure that you have declared this DualListModel globally as below and has getter setter methods

```
private DualListModel<String> cities = new DualListModel<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `PickList pickList = new PickList();` try this:

```
Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
PickList pickList = (PickList) application.createComponent(PickList.COMPONENT_TYPE);
```

---

Change your `pickList.setValue(cities);` for this:

**Note:** *cities* must be a field on your bean with its own getter.

```
ExpressionFactory ef = application.getExpressionFactory();
ELContext elc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
ValueExpression value = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{bean.cities}", DualListModel.class);
pickList.setValueExpression("value", value);
```

Comment: I tried this, and got `Error Rendering View[/pages/DynamicComponent.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeMarkup(PickListRenderer.java:92) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
 at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeEnd(PickListRenderer.java:59) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]` **What might be the root cause?**

Comment: Hmm, I see do you use PrimeFaces 5.3, I have it working on PrimeFaces 7.0, I don't know if this is the reason...